# What is the difference between git pull and rebase?

Tags: git

I was trying to understand the difference between the git pull and rebase, but everywhere I am finding the difference between merge and rebase.

I understand the difference between merge and rebase , but I am worried about how pull and rebase are different as `both bring the latest changes from remote repositories to our local repository.`

Am I correct?

Comment: By default, pull merges, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

`git pull` is a wrapper of two `git` commands: `git fetch` followed by either `git merge` or `git rebase` (with the --rebase option).

It is a convenient command so that you are able to fetch the latest changes and not have to name the remote tracking branch to bring in the new changes with either `pull` or `rebase`.

Answer (score 1):

> both bring the latest changes from remote repositories to our local repository.

That's not correct. `git rebase` will not connect to remote repositories. If you want to make comparisons, the following are reasonable:

`git merge` vs `git rebase`

`git fetch && git merge` vs `git fetch && git rebase`

`git pull` vs `git pull --rebase`

(The latter two lines are comparing the same functionality).

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie to GIT and also trying to understand the significance of these terms  , so thought of adding my 2 bits to it.

**GIT PULL :** 
What i understood from git pull , it is little bit smart and tries to do some extra job for you. So, suppose if you have made some changes in your local repository and you committed them , now after this when you execute the git pull command , it will do two things

```
  git pull origin Dev-1.0 // Dev-1.0 is my remote branch
```

1. It will bring all the latest changes from remote and update your local by invoking `git fetch`.
2. It will also do the implicit merge (extra job) of the code for you , merge comes into the picture when there exists any file which is changed by you and committed and also updated in the repository, then in this case GIT tries to merge these changes. If it is not able to successfully merge those changes then you will get some conflicts that you have to resolve manually.

**GIT Rebase :**
GIT rebase on the other side will bring all the latest changes from remote and apply it in your local and rewind it back to the original state, if you have any commits then it will keep them aside

GIT Experts please feel free to downvote if you think my answer is not correct or require some modifications,but please don't forgot to add your valuable comments.

Comment: The main aspect that you are missing is the `git fetch` part.  That is what updates the head of the remote branch so that you merge/rebase the updated changes from the remote.

Comment: Yeah , in the first point of git pull , i meant that only. I missed that. Thanks for pointing out. Updated my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if attempted answers fit in with SO, but I personally think it's a good idea, and so good on you! Modification needed: `git rebase` *won't* "bring in the latest changes from remote" - you need to `git fetch` to get them.  That's what @Schleis was saying.